# Android create AlertDialog from non activity

Tags: android

I have a little problem with `AlertDialogs` in my application. So here is my situation :

I have a `Synchronization Acitivity` which one is connections to a web service via `HttpURLConnection` and parsing the result from it in different classes. So if the server is response is some kind of error I have an `RPCErrorPacket` which will handle that, but it's not an activity. The parsing of whole response is done in a single `thread` and I need to find a way to create an `AlertDialog` from RPCErrorPacket which will shown in `Synchronization Activity`.

Any ideas if it's possible or how can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Have you used AsyncTask for hitting webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'm doing this :

```
cancelDialog.dismiss();  // cancel the dialog which is already opened
Looper.prepare();  // preparing the looper
this.createDialog("Check your network settings!");  // creating the dialog with method
Looper.loop();   // loop
Looper.myLooper().quit();  // quit looper
Synchronization.this.finish(); // finish activity
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly it is considered bad practice to have services or other background tasks invoke something the user can't avoid. So I would advise that you think about using a [notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) instead. In there you can easily declare what should happen if the user clicks on it.

If your thread is actually a worker for your activity, you should probably use one of the methods Android offers to do asychronous stuff in the background, e.g. an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

runOnUiThread(new runnable{
run()
{
//do required stuff here . pass activity context if required .
});

runOnUIThread is the method which runs a runnable on UI thread from a non UI thread .

Answer (score 0):

it is not good practice but you could save a static instance of your activity in its constructor, then just pass context from that instance to alertdailog on the ui thread ofcourse  `runOnUiThread(new runnable ....)`